# UIImage length vs picture length

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uiimage, base64, jpeg

I'm trying to convert `UIImage` to `Base64` string, and send that to a web-service SOAP then a database.

So, I pick a picture with my app and I try to convert it with this method:

```
public static string GetBase64FromImage (UIImage picture_)
{
    if (picture_ == null)
        return string.Empty;

    NSData data = picture_.AsJPEG();
    Console.WriteLine("JPEG length: " + data.Length);

    byte[] byteArray = new byte[data.Length];
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(data.Bytes, byteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(data.Length));
    string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray);
    Console.WriteLine("Base64 length: "+base64.Length);

    return base64;
}
```

My point here is the total length of the picture.
If I save the picture in file system, and import it, the picture size turns around 1 Mo.
But with my method, JPEG is the double of that (almost 2Mo). So my Base64 turns around 3 Mo which is huge.

Why NSData in JPEG is double size than the "normal" one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JPEG is a compressed data format. Depending on how you save the image (to a file, stream...) you can get different results.

`AsJPEG()` has an overload which accept a `float compressionQuality`. If you do not supply a value the `1.0f` will be used (as default). Since this calls into [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html) you'll get the **least** compression (best image but the largest size) by default. OTOH if you provide `0.0` you'll get the **maximum** compression (smallest size).

Comment: Thank you! Now, my NSData length is around 300Ko with a 0.5f compression. Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, when we take a picture normally, the system compress it a bit (which can explain the double length) ?

Comment: @Gnial0id Yes, JPEG can be loseless (even if compressed) but it's more commonly lossy compressed. Compression is generally good but becomes a problem if you load/change/save the same image several times. Some details at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression#JPEG I'm not aware of any documentation about the internal iOS default wrt compression.